# AWS DMS accesses opensearch as `DOC`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I need to access _doc and create data in the index, but I can't find the
but an error occurs when accessing `doc`.

- OpenSearch 2.7 version
- cloudwatch log

```
2023-09-07T09:37:51 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Elasticsearch:FAILED SourceTable:posts TargetIndex:posts Operation:INSERT_ENTRY RecordPKKey:101 RecordPKID:16DC368A89B428B2485484313BA67A3912CA03F2B2B42429174A4F8B3DC84E44ES HttpCode:400 ESErrorResponse:  
{
    "error": "no handler found for uri [/posts/doc/16DC368A89B428B2485484313BA67A3912CA03F2B2B42429174A4F8B3DC84E44] and method [PUT]"
}
  (elasticsearch_utils.c:668)
```

Can I set this up in the Database Migration Task service?